# Create a simplified versions of a database onto another server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I am required to create a test environment for some of our .Net applications, and some of these applications use only a small portion of some rather large databases.  My idea is to create a 'small' database, which would only hold the tables, stored procedures, views, etc... that are being used by the application.

This will hopefully speed up refresh time on these 'small' databases, however I can't see a simple way of doing this, is there an option to do this easily within SQL server, or via a T-SQL script.

Currently the best method I have is to generate a script from the database, and only select the tables I require with the 'data only' option selected, then run these on the 'small' database to get the data up to date.  However this as you can imagine is a lengthy process and I would prefer to use something a bit more automated.
Any suggestions you can provide are very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Michael Tempest

Comment: is this for mysql or sql-server or both? It is not clear from the questions/tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Database Mirroring** Can be a solution for this problem, Only publish the items/Articles you want on your test Database, You can pause and restart mirroring when needed.
**SSMS Script as** Another wasy way would be go to your SSMS right click the objects you want to copy to test database and Script as Create, do it for all the items you want to move save the scripts in right order i.e (Creating Tables 1st and then relating objects) in one file and run it on the target database.
Since its only you who knows what items to move over to test db I think it will be difficult to find a script which suits your needs. 
Some Useful tips for using SCRIPT AS Option 
To generate the sql script for the objects:

- SQL Server Management Studio > Databases > Database1 > Tasks >
  Generate Scripts...
- The SQL Server Scripts Wizard will start and
  you can choose the objects and settings to export into scripts
- By default the scripting of Indexes and Triggers are not
  included so make sure to trun these on (and any others that you
  are interested in).

To export the data from the tables:

- SQL Server Management Studio > Databases > Database1 > Tasks >
  Export Data...
- Choose the source and destination databases
- Select the tables to export •Make sure to check the Identity Insert
  checkbox for each table so that new identities are not created.

Then create the new database, run the scripts to create all of the objects, and then import the data.

Answer (score 1):

For Dev database we just keep a structural copy of Production one with some data. Periodically we compare databases with tool that compares and syncs database structure (there are plenty of such tools now - we use redgate's one).

For prod_copy database we just do backup-restore of prod db and then truncate biggest tables and shrink database if needed.

If you want completely automate the procedure you can script both SQL Compare or SQL Data Compare. I am not sure if other SQL tools vendors have such an option.